# IWICImagingFactory::CreateDecoderFromStream() fails, error message message is not helpful

Tags: c++, winapi, com, directx, direct2d

I'm trying to load a ID2D1Bitmap from a bitmap resource. To do so, I consulted an [MSDN guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756685%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which told me to use the Windows Imaging Component (IWIC) to process the image before Direct2D uses it.

However, it fails when I call `CreateDecoderFromStream()`, and it returns a strange error message – `0x88982f50` – that tells me nothing. I've searched Google and used DirectX Error Lookup. The DirectX Error Lookup tool only tells me this:

```
HRESULT: 0x88982f50 (2291674960)
Name: Unknown
Description: n/a
Severity code: Failed
Facility Code: FACILITY_DWRITE (2200)
Error Code: 0x2f50 (12112)
```

This is the code I'm using to try and load an ID2D1Bitmap from a resource:

```
int LoadBitmapFromResource( IWICImagingFactory *pIWICFactory, ID2D1RenderTarget *pRT, int resID, ID2D1Bitmap **ppD2DBitmap )
{
    int errmsg;

    HRSRC hbmp;
    HGLOBAL hbmpdata;
    void *pbmp; //system memory pointer to bitmap resource
    DWORD bmpsize;
    IWICStream *pStream;
    IWICBitmapDecoder *pbmpdecoder;
    IWICBitmapFrameDecode *pSource;
    IWICFormatConverter *pConverter;

    hbmp = FindResourceW( GetModuleHandleW(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCEW(resID), RT_BITMAP );
    if( NULL == hbmp )
    {
        printf("LoadBitmapFromResource::FindResourceW() error: %d\r\n", GetLastError() );
        return GetLastError();
    }

    hbmpdata = LoadResource( GetModuleHandleW(NULL), hbmp );
    if( NULL == hbmpdata )
    {
        printf("LoadBitmapFromResource::LoadResource() error: %d\r\n", GetLastError() );
        return GetLastError();
    }

    pbmp = LockResource( hbmpdata );
    if( NULL == pbmp )
    {
        printf("LoadBitmapFromResource::LockResource() error: %d\r\n", GetLastError() );
        return GetLastError();
    }

    bmpsize = SizeofResource( GetModuleHandleW(NULL), hbmp );
    if( NULL == bmpsize )
    {
        printf("LoadBitmapFromResource::SizeofResource() error: %d\r\n", GetLastError() );
        return GetLastError();
    }

    errmsg = pIWICFactory->CreateStream( &pStream );
    if( !SUCCEEDED(errmsg) )
    {
        printf("LoadBitmapFromResource::CreateStream() error: %x\r\n", errmsg );
        return errmsg;
    }

    errmsg = pStream->InitializeFromMemory( (BYTE*)pbmp, bmpsize );
    if( !SUCCEEDED(errmsg) )
    {
        printf("LoadBitmapFromResource::InitializeFromMemory() error: %x\r\n", errmsg );
        return errmsg;
    }

    errmsg = pIWICFactory->CreateDecoderFromStream( pStream, NULL, WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad, &pbmpdecoder );
    if( !SUCCEEDED(errmsg) )
    {
        printf("LoadBitmapFromResource::CreateDecoderFromStream() error: %x\r\n", errmsg );
        return errmsg;
    }

    errmsg = pbmpdecoder->GetFrame( 0, &pSource );
    if( !SUCCEEDED(errmsg) )
    {
        printf("LoadBitmapFromResource::GetFrame() error: %x\r\n", errmsg );
        return errmsg;
    }

    errmsg = pIWICFactory->CreateFormatConverter( &pConverter );
    if( !SUCCEEDED(errmsg) )
    {
        printf("LoadBitmapFromResource::CreateFormatConverter() error: %x\r\n", errmsg );
        return errmsg;
    }

    errmsg = pConverter->Initialize( pSource, GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA, WICBitmapDitherTypeNone, NULL, 0.0f, WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut );
    if( !SUCCEEDED(errmsg) )
    {
        printf("LoadBitmapFromResource::Initialize() error: %x\r\n", errmsg );
        return errmsg;
    }

    errmsg = pRT->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap( pConverter, ppD2DBitmap );
    if( !SUCCEEDED(errmsg) )
    {
        printf("LoadBitmapFromResource::CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap() error: %x\r\n", errmsg );
        return errmsg;
    }

    pConverter->Release();
    pSource->Release();
    pbmpdecoder->Release();
    pStream->Release();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is a WIC error. It corresponds to 'WINCODEC_ERR_COMPONENTNOTFOUND'. [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xwebsupport/archive/2009/09/29/expression-web-studio-2-crashes-on-setup-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-cannot-convert-string-pack-application.aspx) you may find a discussion which may be helpful for you

Comment: ...I see...I'll have to find another way to create an ID2D1Bitmap from a resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I should not be using the WIC decoder for my bitmap resource, because it is apparently raw pixel data that cannot be decoded.

Comment: Just store your bitmap resource in an actual image file format - like PNG or JPG - and it will work. If you store your bitmap resource as raw bitmap data, you don't need to decode it. In that case, just copy the data straight into the target texture..

Answer (score 0):

(I understand this post of a bit old, but I'm putting this here in case it helps someone else or the OP if he happens to ever see this again.)

I have the EXACT same code as you for loading an ID2D1Bitmap from a resource in your exe file using WIC, except mine works perfectly. I can load a bitmap from my exe file flawlessly. The one difference in your code that I see that is different from mine is that instead of using a (BYTE*) cast, I use a reinterpret_cast.

So instead of

```
errmsg = pStream->InitializeFromMemory( (BYTE*)pbmp, bmpsize );
    if( !SUCCEEDED(errmsg) )
    {
        printf("LoadBitmapFromResource::InitializeFromMemory() error: %x\r\n", errmsg );
        return errmsg;
    }
```

I would try doing

```
errmsg = pStream->InitializeFromMemory( reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(pbmp), bmpsize );
    if( !SUCCEEDED(errmsg) )
    {
        printf("LoadBitmapFromResource::InitializeFromMemory() error: %x\r\n", errmsg );
        return errmsg;
    }
```

Comment: Casting to/from BYTE* works the same regardless of which casting operator you use.

Comment: Your probably right, but I still think it could be worth a try. Our code is literally EXACTLY the same except for that one line, so if anyone has this problem, it would be worth a try to see if anything might change using reinterpret_cast instead of explicit conversion or vice versa.

Comment: If you understand casting operations in C/C++, then you likely know the only difference between the differnet operators applies when casting to/from derived classes (where the inheritance heirarchy dictates an offset between base class addresses or v-table offset) such that the result of the cast is a different memory address.  For general casting between plain-old-data types, the resulting address does not change.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens because the bitmap data returned by LockResource() does not contains the first 14 bytes bitmap header. You can compare the data returned from LockResource() and the original bitmap file to see that. Here is the simple test code in C. You can add it after SizeofResource() then check the out.bmp file, which is an invalid bitmap file. And because of the bad image data, it does not have any valid decoder (WINCODEC_ERR_COMPONENTNOTFOUND).

```
    FILE* file;
    fopen_s( &file, "out.bmp", "wb");
    fwrite((const char*)(pbmp), 1, bmpsize, file);
    fclose(file);
```

There are two obvious solutions.

1. Do not create IWICStream/IWICBitmapDecoder from resource. Instead, using external bitmap file directly to create them. Check MSDN's sample code about that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/how-to-load-a-direct2d-bitmap-from-a-file
2. Add the bitmap header in front of the resource data. Something like:

   ```
    BITMAPFILEHEADER header;
    header.bfType = 0x4D42; // 'BM'
    header.bfSize = bmpsize + 14; // resource data size + 14 bytes header
    header.bfReserved1 = 0;
    header.bfReserved2 = 0;
    header.bfOffBits = 14 + 40; // details in bitmap format

    BYTE* buffer = new BYTE[header.bfSize];

    memcpy(buffer, &header, 14);
    memcpy(buffer + 14, pbmp, bmpsize);

    // Initialize the stream with the memory pointer and size.
    hr = pStream->InitializeFromMemory(
        reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(buffer),
        header.bfSize
    );
   ```

Be careful, the 'buffer' has to be alive during the life cycle of IWICStream.